# JavaFX: Can not retrieve property '...' in PropertyValueFactory

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy intentando mostrar la información de mi tabla ModeloVenta en un TableView en JavaFX pero consigo el siguiente error:

```
Can not retrieve property 'nombre' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@6d44f093 with provided class type: class Modelo.ModeloVentas
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class Modelo.ModeloVentas (in module com.example.lab12_12_12_12) because module com.example.lab12_12_12_12 does not open Modelo to javafx.base
```

Busque y vi que se tenia que crear un nuevo metodo --StringProperty nombreProperty()-- pero aun así el error sigue apareciendo.
Estoy trabajando con IntelliJ, IDK 16, JavaFx 16.

**Clase ModeloVentas:**
Elimine algunos métodos y solo estoy trabajando con la columna nombre

```
public class ModeloVentas {
    public IntegerProperty codigo;
    public StringProperty nombre, cantidad, precio;


    public ModeloVentas(int codigo, String cantidad, String nombre, String precio) {
        this.nombre = new SimpleStringProperty(nombre);
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre.get();
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = new SimpleStringProperty(nombre);
    }
    public StringProperty nombreProperty() {
        return nombre;
    }
```

**Función para llenar la información:**

```
public static void llenarInfo(Connection conn, ObservableList<ModeloVentas> lista){
    try {
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultado = sta.executeQuery("SELECT Codigo, Nombre, Cantidad, Precio FROM ventas");
        while(resultado.next()){
            lista.add(
                    new ModeloVentas(
                            resultado.getString("Nombre")
                    )
            );
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
public class HelloController implements Initializable{
@FXML public TableView<ModeloVentas> res;
public ConexionSQL conn;
public ObservableList<ModeloVentas> listaVentas;

//Columnas

@FXML public TableColumn<ModeloVentas, String> colNombre;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

conn = new ConexionSQL();
try {
    conn.establecerConexion();
    listaVentas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ModeloVentas.llenarInfo(conn.getConn(), listaVentas);
    res.setItems(listaVentas);


    //Enlazar Columnas con atributos
    
    colNombre.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ModeloVentas, String>("nombre"));
   

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Así se añada no cambia el error...O si el compañero puede por favor decir si ya le funcionó y publicar el código, ya que tambien estoy desde hace mucho rato intentando visualizar en un tableView datos de Mysql y tampoco lo he logrado

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta está en la  misma pregunta "because module com.example.lab12_12_12_12 does not open Modelo to javafx.base"
un modulo no tiene acceso a otro
en module-info.java de su proyecto tiene que añadir.

```
opens com.example.lab12_12_12_12  to javafx.base ;
```

convencionalmente los paquetes no se nombran con números ni underscore
[namming convention java](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-java-naming-conventions-2034199)